# Integer partitions of 12 given odd and even conditions to the components.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How many integer solutions are there to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4=12$ with $x_1$ and $x_2$ odd and $x_3$ and $x_4$ even?


So I know that for the integer $12$ there are $p(12)=77$ partitions and I have also deduced there are $15$ partitions of the integer $12$ of size $4$. Where I'm stuck is determining how many of these have $x_1$ and $x_2$ odd and $x_3$ and $x_4$ even.

Comment: Edit: I'm also not sure if the integers $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ can be in any order of if they must go descending?

Comment: If you ask for integer solutions there are infinitely many because some of the variables can be negative.   You probably mean positive or nonnegative integer solutions.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes! Sorry - *positive integer solutions

Comment: If there's the additional constraint that they must be descending, your best best is probably just to enumerate them explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract $1$ from the last two, giving four even numbers that sum to $10$.  Divide them all by $2$, giving four numbers that sum to $5$.  Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: So would the answer just be $1$? As there is just $1$ sum of $4$ numbers that add to $5$? Therefore the solution to my original question would be: $5 + 3 + 2 + 2$ ?

Comment: Normally we treat problems like this as depending on order, so there are $4$ sequences of $4$ positive numbers that sum to $5$.  If they must be descending, you are correct.